# Setting height style property of React Navigation's Material Top Tab Navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm making top tab using [MaterialTopTabNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/material-top-tab-navigator.html). But there is an issue on style.

I can set style of `MaterialTopTabNavigator` using several styles. And when I set the height of **tab**, the container's height is changed, not the **tab** I think. Below images is a sample.

1. The style objects before applying height

```
labelStyle: {
    color: '#7d3aff',
    fontSize: 12,
    lineHeight: 12,
    backgroundColor: '#a0f312',
  },
  tabStyle: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#7d3aff',
    borderRadius: 10,
    backgroundColor: '#f012',
  },
  style: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  indicatorStyle: {
    height: 0,
  },
```

and the tab image.

[image]

2. The style objects after applying height

```
labelStyle: {
    color: '#7d3aff',
    fontSize: 12,
    lineHeight: 12,
    backgroundColor: '#a0f312',
  },
  tabStyle: {
    height: 30, // the only change is here
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#7d3aff',
    borderRadius: 10,
    backgroundColor: '#f012',
  },
  style: {
    // height: 30, // there is no difference do it or apply height in tabStyle
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  indicatorStyle: {
    height: 0,
  },
```

and the tab image

[image]

As you saw, the height is applied on **container** of **tab bar**, not on **tab** or **tab bar**, i,e, there is no change in tab's height.

How can I apply height to every tabs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason of it is `minHeight` and `maxHeight`. The `tabStyle` object has `minHeight` as default. So if you set `minHeight` and `maxHeight`, then you can apply `height` to it.

```
tabStyle: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: colors.primary,
    borderRadius: 10,
    backgroundColor: '#f012',
    minHeight: 10,
    maxHeight: 30,
  },
```

[image]

Comment: I added minHeight and maxHeight to TabStyle, then added height to style, made no difference. Then I tried adding height to TabStyle; made no difference. When I added height to tabBarStyle in screenOptions, the height changed, but the tab labels got pushed up. This is all quite messy and non-intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is suffering from this issue, try reducing the margins from the `tabBarContentContainerStyle` inside the screen options. This both reduces top and bottom container with the labels.

```
tabBarContentContainerStyle: {
    marginTop: -10,
    marginBottom: -10,
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the height of the TabBar using screenOptions, not tabBarOptions. apply height in the tabBarStyle property.

```
screenOptions={({ route }) => ({ 
   tabBarStyle: { height: 40 },
```

However, it pushes the tab bar labels up off the screen, probably have to add padding to them.

Solution: Wrap your Text labels in a View, applying flex, and flex-direction: column to the View. Then you have control over the vertical spacing of the labels.